# SVG shows not correctly in Firefox browser

Tags: firefox, svg, fonts

I have next svg object which shown well in Chrome and AI, but it shows not correctly in Firefox. In my svg i have 2 textPath tags, i try to set italic font-style for both of them however only 1 textPath effected. How can i fix it if i still want 2 textPath elements be in 1 svg object?

```html
<svg width="229" height="95" viewBox="0 0 98.59523272091116 43.1456805813697" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="none"><g id="0.13161635632674862"><text fill="#FF0000" stroke="#FFFF00" data-stroke="FFFF00" stroke-width="0px" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="" y="2.1527343388845233" text-anchor="start" font-size="24px" font-family="Carter One" data-textcurve="1" data-itemzoom="1 1" data-textspacing="0" style="font-style: italic; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none;font-family: 'Carter One';" itemzoom="0.4305468677769046 0.45416505875126006"><textPath xlink:href="#textPath-item-4" style="stroke: rgb(255, 255, 0); stroke-width: 3.31429px;" data-stroke="rgb(255, 255, 0)"><tspan dy="0">Create</tspan></textPath><textPath xlink:href="#textPath-item-4"><tspan dy="0" style="stroke-width: 0px;">Create</tspan></textPath></text></g><defs><path id="textPath-item-4" d="M 4.5 28.240596987479876 A 5443.099053742821 5443.099053742821 0 0 1 99.4987942273035 28.240596987479876"></path><style>@font-face {
    font-family: 'Carter One';
  src: local('Carter One'), local('CarterOne'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/carterone/v9/VjW2qt1pkqVtO22ObxgEBfk_vArhqVIZ0nv9q090hN8.woff2) format('woff2');
}</style></defs></svg>
```

[image]

Comment: Displays fine for me on Mac Firefox 56

Comment: I can see the problem on Firefox 56/Linux. Setting a `stroke-width` other than 0 cancels the `font-style: italic`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the font you selected, `Carter One`, has no italics variant. So the browser needs to use a fallback (which, as far as I know, amounts to skewing the glyphs). Firefox seems to fail with the simultanuous task of "inventing" an italics font, painting a stroke and writing it on a text path.

It is not a problem to use multiple textPath elements inside one text. Only when using both a non-zero `stroke-width` and `font-style:italics` a font with a known italics style needs to be referenced. For example `Lato` has one:

```html
<svg width="229" height="95" viewBox="0 0 98.59523272091116 43.1456805813697" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<g id="0.13161635632674862">
  <text fill="#FF0000" stroke="#FFFF00" data-stroke="FFFF00" stroke-width="0px" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="" y="2.1527343388845233" text-anchor="start" font-size="24px" font-family="Carter One" data-textcurve="1" data-itemzoom="1 1" data-textspacing="0" style="font-style: italic; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none;font-family: 'Ubuntu';" itemzoom="0.4305468677769046 0.45416505875126006">
    <textPath xlink:href="#textPath-item-4" style="stroke: rgb(255, 255, 0); stroke-width: 3.31429px;" data-stroke="rgb(255, 255, 0)"><tspan dy="0">Create</tspan></textPath>
    <textPath xlink:href="#textPath-item-4"><tspan dy="0" style="stroke-width: 0px;">Create</tspan></textPath>
  </text>
</g>
<defs>
  <path id="textPath-item-4" d="M 4.5 28.240596987479876 A 5443.099053742821 5443.099053742821 0 0 1 99.4987942273035 28.240596987479876"></path>
  <style>
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Ubuntu Bold Italic'), local('Ubuntu-BoldItalic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ubuntu/v11/4iCp6KVjbNBYlgoKejZPslyPN4E.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215;
}
  </style>
</defs>
</svg>
```

As an aside, while I don't know exactly which browsers support it, at least most modern browsers seem to know the `paint-order` CSS property, which removes the need to paint the text twice. `paint-order:stroke` paints the stroke below the fill:

```html
<svg width="229" height="95" viewBox="0 0 98.59523272091116 43.1456805813697" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<g id="0.13161635632674862">
  <text fill="#FF0000" stroke="#FFFF00" data-stroke="FFFF00" stroke-width="0px" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="" y="2.1527343388845233" text-anchor="start" font-size="24px" font-family="Carter One" data-textcurve="1" data-itemzoom="1 1" data-textspacing="0" style="font-style: italic; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none;font-family: 'Ubuntu';" itemzoom="0.4305468677769046 0.45416505875126006">
    <textPath xlink:href="#textPath-item-4" style="stroke: rgb(255, 255, 0); stroke-width: 3.31429px;paint-order:stroke" data-stroke="rgb(255, 255, 0)"><tspan dy="0">Create</tspan></textPath>
</g>
<defs>
  <path id="textPath-item-4" d="M 4.5 28.240596987479876 A 5443.099053742821 5443.099053742821 0 0 1 99.4987942273035 28.240596987479876"></path>
  <style>
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Ubuntu Bold Italic'), local('Ubuntu-BoldItalic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ubuntu/v11/4iCp6KVjbNBYlgoKejZPslyPN4E.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215;
}
  </style>
</defs>
</svg>
```